# performance issue Spark LSH MinHash approxSimilarityJoin

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, lsh

I'm joining 2 datasets one with 6 million and another with 11 million records using Apache Spark ML LSH's approxSimilarityJoin method.

I have tried with shuffle partitions 500to 2000, last 2 tasks get stuck forever.
Executors are 50 executor memory is 50GB

What else can be done?

Comment: First, If you want to make it working, try increasing the input token length for example if you are using Ngram try to increase the length of the Ngram as it will be less frequent and will help avoid data skewness. Second, you can try to create a ngrams and filter some of the frequent ngrams to avoid skewed data. That should resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks Karan Sharma. How do handle false negatives.I am missing a few matches pairs

Comment: Before actually dropping the duplicates you can compute the true Jaccard distance and reduce false negatives. This will be expensive though but still better than brute force.